# ERROR Unrecognized option: --module-path JAVAFX - ARCHIVE MAIN

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred.

Hello friends, I'm facing problems with JAVAFX. I configured the  module path with VM options correctly, and it still shows an error, I'm using Netbeans, any suggestions?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: If `--module-path` is not being recognized, then you're likely using Java 8 or older. Modules, and thus options such as `--module-path`, were added in Java 9. Note the current LTS release of Java is 17, while the latest release is 19. The latest release of JavaFX is 19. If you're trying to use Java/JavaFX 11+, then read the documentation linked by SedJ601.

Comment: I managed to solve the dependency problem, the javafx version is 19 and java 18. And the error is now Error: JavaFX runtime components were not found. They are mandatory to run this app

Comment: Please try to follow the directions in the linked documentation exactly (on the left of the page, you'll see "JavaFX and NetBeans"). This is to make sure you can get a basic example application up and running. From there, you can start coding your own project.